# is it possible to check the talk time consumed by users using opentok

Tags: php, webrtc, opentok

**What am I doing**

I integrated opentok with our membership site and it is working perfectly fine. Our website is a member based site where you can signup and hold one on one video conferences with your clients who schedule a meeting with you.

**What my understanding is of opentok**

I understand that there is a monthly fee involved and then based on the number of minutes i utilized, i get billed. (of course after the first 10K minutes)

**What I want to know**

Since people will be signing up to use our service, I wanted to keep track of which user is consuming how many minutes. So is there a way to keep track of which user consumed how much talk time on OpenTok?

I will really appreciate any guidance here.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with opentok or webrtc. you just want to count the amount of time that a user accesses a certain page...since they have logins already you should be able to track it from the server. Or kick off a timer signal to the server once getusermedia is fired.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but what you are suggesting is a bit risky. The page members use to conduct video conference can be accessed any time even if the meeting did not start, assume that the meeting scheduled is tomorrow and today you just logged in to browse around and happen to visit the video conference page as well then what?

Comment: Then, you can start a timer when the peerconnection is started and SDPs are starting to be exchanged.

Comment: This is where I need help, how to do that? do you have any examples that i can look into? the website i am working in is developed in PHP and JavaScript

Comment: You can send a signal to your PHP server and keep track of start and end times in a database and just keep tallies on it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will look into that, lets see what other experts have to say about it

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on @benjamintrent's comments, here are some OpenTok specific sample codes. It really depends on how you would want to bill your users, here are 2 cases:

If you want to start billing users the moment they go into the chat, you can send a post request to your server indicating start time:

```
session.on("sessionConnected", function(err){
  if(!err){
    $.post("/server/userId", {startTime: date.now()}, function(){...});
  }
});
```

In most cases, you probably want to start billing when users are actually connected to the users they were supposed to be connected to:

```
session.on("streamCreated", function(stream){
  if(stream.connection.connectionData == "username I was supposed to connect to"){
    $.post("/server/userId", {startTime: date.now()}, function(){...});
  }
});
```

You probably want to end a video chat session when he is disconnected from a session, or if the person you are supposed to talk to leaves the chatroom:

```
session.on("streamDestroyed", function(stream){
  if(stream.connection.connectionData == "username I was supposed to connect to"){
    $.post("/server/userId", {endTime: date.now()}, function(){...});
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, if a user closes the browser, you will not get sessionDisconnected or streamDestroyed event. To overcome this, you can send a heartbeat post request to your server every 5 seconds. Your server will know that user has closed their browser if it stops receiving a heartbeat request and end the billing accordingly.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.post("/heartbeat/userId", {currentTime: date.now()}, function(){...});
}, 5000);
```

Hope that helped, good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @songz, I really appreciate it, could you please tell me what this does `$.post("/server/userId", {startTime: date.now()}, function(){...});` did you see this in their documentation?